# Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress

У меня задание сделать кастомный пост тайп **без использования плагинов**. Он должен изменять один из статических блоков на сайте.

Сам блок имеет следующие поля:

- текст отзыва
- автор
- фото автора
- дата публикации

Не могу понять как задать эти поля в меню добавления поста? Пробовал использовать свойство custom-fields, но выходит что-то бредовое. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Что такое " кастомный пост тайп" и каким к нему боком  блок с полями?

Answer (score 1):

https://wp-kama.ru/ тут есть все про пост тайпов, без плагина

Comment: Суть в том что не вышло. Вернее совсем не то что нужно по ТЗ.

Comment: По ТЗ - это на биржу фриланса.

Comment: Никто же не просит сделать. Вопрос состоит в том, как в пост тайп добавить свои кастомные поля? И что по данным из источника, сделать это не получилось.